# Centralized Swagger/OpenAPI UI for all the different microservices on a single swagger URL i.e accessing all the URLs through one

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, microservices, openapi

I have around 16 microservices built in Spring Boot that communicate with each other and each microservice is having multiple APIs in it. I have configured OpenAPI for each of the microservices. So it gives me 16 "swagger-ui" URLs.
I wonder how can I centralize all Swagger URLs on one single page; I want only 1 swagger URL to access all the 16 microservices.

I have gone through the following as well but didn't get any solution
[Centralize Swagger at one place for All microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796011/centralize-swagger-at-one-place-for-all-microservices)

Please guide me to the best way to achieve it.

Comment: No reply for following as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334525/how-to-integrate-openapi-specifications-from-different-apis

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/108#issuecomment-665789037). It works with Spring Cloud Discovery but can be easily adapted to other discovery solutions. The basic idea is to generate for Swagger the list of URLs pointing to the OpenAPI JSON files.

The result is similar to one in the @shadyx's answer, but the list is generated dynamically

```java
@RestController
public class SwaggerUiConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @GetMapping("/swagger-config.json")
    public Map<String, Object> swaggerConfig() {
        List<SwaggerUrl> urls = new LinkedList<>();
        discoveryClient.getServices().forEach(serviceName -> 
                        discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceName).forEach(serviceInstance ->
                                urls.add(new SwaggerUrl(serviceName, serviceInstance.getUri() + "/v3/api-docs"))
                        )
        );
        return Map.of("urls", urls);
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    configUrl: "/swagger-config.json"
```

Sample of the generated `swagger-config.json`

```json
{
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8088/v3/api-docs/users",
      "name": "users"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8088/v3/api-docs/stores",
      "name": "stores"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you µservices use the same host, you can create a Spring Boot µservice which acts as a openAPI gateway using `spring-doc`. (If they are not using the same host, you will have to deal with CORS issues)

1. First, add the following dependencies to your new gateway µservice

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Then, add the below configuration

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    configUrl: ${server.servlet.contextPath}/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    url: ${server.servlet.contextPath}/v3/api-docs
    urls:
      - name: api-customer
        url: /customer/v3/api-docs
      - name: api-cart
        url: /cart/v3/api-docs
      - name: api-product
        url: /product/v3/api-docs
```

For each µservice you have to fill in the `url` property with is the url to the openAPI definition at json or yaml format.

For `springdoc` library which uses openAPI 3.0 the default url is `/${µServiceContextPath}/v3/api-docs`
For `springfox` library which uses openAPI 2.0 the default url is `/${µServiceContextPath}/v2/api-docs`

3. Finally access to /${contextPath}/swagger-ui.html and you will be able to select an openAPI

[image]